# Why do contacts repeat in listview?

Tags: android

I was following an example off of the android site.  I am new to android development.  The problem I am having is that my contacts repeat over and over, about 6 times.  Can anyone figure out why?  I feel it may have to do with my imports as they were not included with the example but I am not certain.  Also note that I did not create an xml file for the listview under res.
Thanks,

*ListViewLoader.java*

```
package com.example.contactlist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;

//from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };

    // This is the select criteria
    static final String SELECTION = "((" + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " != '' ))";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
        String[] fromColumns = { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME };
        int[] toViews = { android.R.id.text1 }; // The TextView in
                                                // simple_list_item_1

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, fromColumns,
                toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    // Called when a new Loader needs to be created
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data
    // unavailable
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed. We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something when a list item is clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: May hope taht [site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500325/list-view-item-repeated-in-android) would help!!

Comment: This example seems different than mine as in they are using different methods, so it is difficult to apply their solution to my issue.  I've had the same issue when trying to search for other examples on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out the solution.  I needed to query the Contacts table instead of the Data table.  Apparently the Data table has duplicates.  I've pasted a portion of my updated code.

```
public class ListViewLoader extends ListActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {



    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve
    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

    // This is the select criteria
    static final String SELECTION = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " != '' ))";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
        String[] fromColumns = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        int[] toViews = { android.R.id.text1 }; // The TextView in
                                                // simple_list_item_1

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, fromColumns,
                toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        System.out.println("oncreate (Bundle)");        
    }

    // Called when a new Loader needs to be created
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.

        System.out.println("oncreateloader");
        System.out.println(PROJECTION);
        System.out.println(SELECTION);

        return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

    }
```

Comment: thanks ,its working like charm but How can i get contact number with name?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
mAdapter.swapCursor(data)
```

to

```
mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)
```

and

```
mAdapter.swapCursor(null)
```

to

```
mAdapter.changeCursor(null)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution although contacts are still repeating after trying this.  From some more reading it may be that the contacts are repeating because they are in multiple groups.  I am not certain how to check this, but it could be the case.  I heard that importing them into a separate database may be a solution if this is the problem.  Have not been able to implement a solution yet.